# Is learning Python 2 along with 3 a waste of effort?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming, and have decided to start by learning Python; I've only been studying it for a little over a month, so I am very much still a beginner. Thus far, I really love the language, and am starting to grasp some of it.

But that brings me to my question/concerns; because I am currently only trying to teach myself Python, most of any source that I find to teach myself, be it a book, videos or tutorials, are written for Python 2, and only occasionally for 3.

So, is learning Python 2 going to make it more difficult for me, or slow me down? I really feel that I like the feel of Python 3 much more, but I am mostly learning 2. If I grasp the core concepts of Python in 2, will that translate into 3 easily?

I just want to make sure that I won't regret having put much of my effort into 2, if it is going to make 3 more challenging.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not the type of question SO is for. You could try asking this at quora or some other website.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but, in my opinion, asking which version is more suitable for beginner-learning is on-topic when the community believes in a 'correct' answer.

Comment: agree with dietbacon, this is a better quora-type question.  SO is much better for "how do i ..." kinds of questions.  That being said, the majority of Python 2 you learn will apply to Python 3, so you won't lose out too much if you study Python 2 at the beginning.

Comment: I guess I am trying to ask "how do I" learn Python lol, but thank you :) I'll check out Quora!

Comment: related: [Какую версию Python выбрать?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/365114/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Learn Python 3 first.  It's the future of Python and 2.x is in the rear-view mirror for most of the core developers.

Learning Python 2.7.x won't be a waste of your time, as you'll often run into it "in the wild," but it takes years to gain mastery, so you might as well start on the path that will be the most relevant when you become fluent in the language.

Comment: Thank you, I'll continue to learn Python to as I go, and try to find more Python 3 resources, and slowly shift to learning mainly how to write proper Python 3 code, in stead of 2..